# How to manage the collections properly with backbone and mongoDB schemas on a basic case

Tags: mongodb, backbone.js, mongoose

I tried 2 different ways to manage the collections, the second one sounds cleaner to me but i can't make it works.

I come here to know what is the best way to organise your code on backbone and mongoDB schemas on this very basic situation (and why the second one doesn't works)

In my both example, the situation is a `collection Friends` within a `Model User`

**First example (works well)**

**Client side**

```
App.Models.User = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults : {
        username : "example",
        Friends: []
    },
});
```

**Server side**

```
UserSchema : {
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            unique: true
        },
        Friends:
        [ {
            user_id: {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'User'
            },
            status: {
                type: Boolean
            },
        }]
```

With this method, when i populate the `Friends references` from a `User document`, backbone get well the collection when i fetch it from the client side.

**Second example (seems cleaner to me but fail when fetching the collection)**

**Client side**

```
App.Models.User = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults : {
        username : "example",
        status: [], //Since Friends is now a collection i build an array to index each user_id according to its status.
        Friends: new App.Collections.User()
    },
});
```

**Server side**

```
UserSchema : {
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            unique: true
        },
        status: [ {
          user_id: {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'User'
            },
          value: Bolean 
        } ],
        Friends:
        [ {
            user_id: {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'User'
            }
        }]
```

**App.Collections.User**

```
App.Collections.User = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: App.Models.User,

    initialize : function() {

    },

    getFriends: function(callback) {
        console.log('getFriends called!');
        this.url = App.url+'friends';
        this.fetch({
            success: function(collection, response, options) {
                console.log('fetch OK');
                console.log(collection.toJSON());
                callback(true);
            },
            error: function(collection, response, options) {
                console.log('fetch KO');
                callback(false);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

With this method, when i fetch the `Friends collection`, i get an error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (on chrome)` or `TypeError: this.model is not a constructor (on firebug)`, both on `backbone-0.9.9.js (ligne 26)`

It happens just before being inside the `success callback` from the `collection's fetch` method and only when there is a collection returned from the server ide (when it's null there is no issue, like if backbone can't parse it).

The JSON returned looks like:

```
   [
      {
          "__v": 0,
          "_id": "5137cdf1538238073f000005",
          "username": "Someone Else",
          "status": [
           {
             "user_id": "5137cb9b730754a666000006",
              value: true
           }
          ],
          "Friends": [
            {
              "user_id": "5137cb9b730754a666000006",
              "_id": "5137cf2e0399fd7c3f000005"
            }
          ],
        },
        "_id": "5137cf2e0399fd7c3f000006"
      }
    ]
```

So what is the best way to organise your code between this both method ? And why do you think i get this error with the second one (is my JSON invalid ?) ?

Comment: Show us your code for App.Collections.User

Comment: @glortho i just have added it, `console.log('getFriends called!');` is launched and the error appears just after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that the return from your collection api is a valid json.
The example json return that you have provided is not valid

You can check the validity by copy pasting the sample json string here

http://jsonlint.com/